# Cake php 2.10 login with http basic auth in controller action

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, basic-authentication

I'm working on a legacy project built with Cake PHP 2.10 and need to conditionally utilise HTTP basic auth in one of my controller's action. It's currently set up to utilise the `identify` method with the request from within the controller action and I need to get it to use HTTP basic auth.

I've set it up in my controller action but when passing my username and password in as http basic via Postman, `$user` is returning a boolean value of `true` always, regardless of whether I'm logged in or not.

What am I missing here?

```php
public function appv6()
{
  header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");

  $this->Auth->sessionKey = false;
  $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
  $user = $this->Auth->login();

  var_dump($user);
  die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call `$this->Auth->login()` when Basic Auth is used. I think that at the time when you call it the user has already been authenticated.

> Because basic and digest authentication don’t require an initial POST or a form so if using only basic / digest authenticators you don’t require a login action in your controller... Stateless authentication will re-verify the user’s credentials on each request...

https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-digest-and-basic-authentication-for-logging-in